# Container changes only height

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The Problem is when I change width of the container of the UserMessage it does not change it it changes only the height.

I got this container it is basically a where the live chat is in.

```
child: Listener(
                            onPointerDown: _chatTouchedTrue,
                            onPointerUp: _chatTouchedFalse,
                             child: Container(
                                 width: 130, //it only changes when I edit it here
                                 height: 230,
                            child: AnimatedList(
                                key: listKey,
                                controller: _listScrollController,
                                initialItemCount: names.length,
                                itemBuilder:
                                    (context, index, animation) {
                                  return slideMessage(
                                      context, index, animation);
                                })))
```

This is the Animation for how the new messages should slide in.

```
Widget slideMessage(BuildContext context, int index, animation) {
    String userName = names[index];
    String message = messages[index];
    return SlideTransition(
        position: Tween<Offset>(
          begin: const Offset(0, 1),
          end: Offset(0, 0),
        ).animate(animation),
        child: UserMessage(
          userName: userName,
          message: message,
        ));
  }
```

And this is the child of the Animation (UserMessage(..)) this is how the text message will look at the end.

```
Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.3),
     child: Container(

          width: 10,  //it does not change the width here
          height: 17,
          child: Align(
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                TextSpan(
                  text: widget.userName,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 9,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 250, 250, 100)),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: widget.message,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 9,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(220, 220, 220, 100)),
                )
              ]),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color.fromRGBO(1, 1, 1, 0.2),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
          ),
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is pretty clear and you can read about it in the official documentation for the container class: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html

When the **parent** of the *container* widget doesn't provide bounded constraints then the *container* wraps around its child to be as small as possible.

So in order to fix the issue and get what you want simply add **SizedBox** for the parent of your *container* and set the **width and height in the SizedBox**.

Comment: The new structure is like this now but still not works
`Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.3),
        child: SizedBox(
            width: 10,
            height: 17,
            child: Container(`

Comment: Could you try to set the SizedBox to be the parent and move the padding where the SizedBox now is. Something like this:

SizeBox(
    width: 10,
    height: 17,
    child:
        Padding(
           child: Container(

Comment: I changed it but it did not work, I also tried to have a Structure like: Padding, Container, Richtext

Comment: that's really strange, did you look up in the inspector what the properties are? maybe you will find something useful there

Comment: I have never used the flutter inspector but I dont see anything weird
http://prntscr.com/w7uzda
http://prntscr.com/w7uzl6

I replaced the padding and stuff but it is still the same error

Comment: so you got no clue?

Comment: sorry, nothing.. this should be pretty straight forward, we are missing some point in the code somwhere.. I can only point you to this nice tutorial how to impl animated lists:

https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-animate-items-in-list-using-animatedlist-in-flutter-9b1a64e9aa16

Comment: I got the animations and stuff from this tutorial, should I send you my whole code anywhere?